# Javascript call to function not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with a script javascript. I have an object with inside some function and variable. In one of these function i make an ajax request and inside the error handler i call a function defined in the same object but the debugger say that the function  is "not available" but the variables defined in the object are visible...

This is the portion of Javascript with the object:

```
Utils = {
"defaultErrorMessage" : "Ci scusiamo per il disagio ma qualcosa è andato storto, probabilmente è una cosa temporanea, ritenta in un altro momento",
"base_url" : $('#base_url').val(),
getApiUri : function(name) {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + PATH[ENV] + name + ENV == 'stub' ? '.json' : '';
},

callServer : function(uri, data, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.base_url + "index.php/" + uri,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            waitingDialog.show('Caricamento...');
        },
        success:
            function (data) {

                //alert(data);  //as a debugging message.
                successCallback(data);
            },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //alert("Qualcosa di storto: "+ xhr.status + " messaggio: " + xhr.responseText);
            this.showModalDialog('error','Siamo spiacenti :(', this.defaultErrorMessage);
        },
        complete: function() {
            waitingDialog.hide();
        }
    });
},

hideAllMessages: function ()
{
    var messagesHeights = new Array(); // this array will store height for each

    for (i=0; i<myMessages.length; i++)
    {
        messagesHeights[i] = $('.' + myMessages[i]).outerHeight();
        $('.' + myMessages[i]).css('top', -messagesHeights[i]); //move element outside viewport
    }
},

showMessage: function(type, title, message) {
    var title = (typeof title !== 'undefined') ? title : '';
    var message = (typeof message !== 'undefined') ? message : '';

    this.hideAllMessages();
    if (title != '')
        $('.'+type + ' h3').html(title);
    if (message != '')
        $('.'+type + ' p').html(message);
    $('.'+type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
},

showModalDialog: function(type, title, message, withOK) {
    var withOK = (typeof withOK !== 'undefined') ? withOK : false;
    $div = $('<div id="error" title="'+title+'">');
    $div.append('<p>'+message+'</p>');
    if (!withOK) {
        $div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            maxHeight: 500
        }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", colorDialog[type]);
    }
    else {
        $div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            maxHeight: 500,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", colorDialog[type]);
    }
},

validateEmail: function(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

};

Why **this.showModalDialog** is not available in the error handler? I have tried also without "this" but is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't always work in callback functions because the context changes so `this` is referring to something that is no longer your `Utils` object. The way to fix this is by keeping a variable to remember what your context is when you need it. In your `callServer` function, before the ajax call, add `var self = this`. And then when you need to reference showModalDialog, you can call it with `self.showModalDialog();`

```
callServer : function(uri, data, successCallback) {
     var self = this;
     $.ajax({
       ...
          self.showModalDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` represents your object in `callServer`, but it doesn't have the same meaning inside the function you're passing to your Ajax call, there instead represents the object you're passing to `$.ajax()` as argument.

You need to pass it as another variable like `self`.

Inside `callServer`

```
var self = this;
```

Inside you error handler

```
self.showModalDialog();
```